# How to block right click in an particular area in HTML?

Tags: html, css

## How to block right click in a particular area in HTML?

---

Like on youtube they have blocked right click on the area of the video player yet it works normally on the other area of the page...

---

I also want to block right click where I embed my video using `<video></video>` tag.

Comment: reference with illustration - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu

Answer (score 0):

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false"></video>
```

this runs a javascript command when you right click (opens the context-menu inside the video-tag)

you could also do this:

either way it prevents the default action (opening the contextmenu).